# Stopping a click event on a div if a condition is met -- Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, event-handling

I have a loop that generates let's say 20 divs. Each div is an object from my local objects array. Here's the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInventory"
           class="col-2 c-pointer"
           (click)="addItemToArray(item)">
        <img src="{{item.image}}" class="img-fluid"/>
        <span class="d-block">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on the div(item) it will add the item to an array:

```
addItemToArray(item) {
    this.itemsToSend.push(item);
    item.isAdded = true;
  }
```

The user under no circumstances is allowed to add the same item twice in the array, but I do not want to mutate the `userInventory` array (or `splice()` it). I want it to still be visible, just change some styles on it so it looks disabled. Also as you can see, when the item is clicked, `item.isAdded` becomes `true`.

**What I want to do is**, when `item.isAdded` is true, disable the (click) event listener on the div (and add some styles), so that the user cannot add the same item twice, despite clicking on it multiple times.

Is this doable in the current Angular implementation?

Comment: add an `if` statement in your view to check wether the `item.isAdded` is true or false. If true, then add the (onclick) else don't add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that, you can add a class for each items which are added in the cart as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInventory"
     class="col-2 c-pointer"
     [class.disabled]="item.isAdded" <!-- Add this class, and customize its look -->
     (click)="addItemToArray(item)">
  <img src="{{item.image}}" class="img-fluid"/>
  <span class="d-block">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Then, in your `.ts` component file, add this condition:

```
addItemToArray(item) {
    if (!item.isAdded) {
        this.itemsToSend.push(item);
        item.isAdded = true;
    } else {
        // add some error flash message
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Ended up using your solution. It escaped me that it can be done so simple and concise. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the other solutions below, but the advantage of this one, is that you can add some flash messages when the user attempts to re-add the same item. Good luck! :)

Comment: In these situations, where the "else" case is the one to trigger an error, I prefer to put it first: `if (fail condition) { // return or handle fail path }` then you can continue with the function (not nested in any other block) and rest assured that your error case is handled. Just my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 9):

try it with a condition:

```
(click)="!item.isAdded && addItemToArray(item)"
```

Answer (score 3):

For the class, you can use this :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInventory" [class.disabled]="item.isAdded">
```

(I removed attributes for the sake of readability)

For the click, you can use a ternary :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInventory" (click)="item.isAdded ? null : addItemToArray(item)">
```

But the best solution would simply be to use a condition in your click handler I think.

Comment: Yeah but that's not very clear, if it were my project I would rather use the click handler for my condition

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `disabled` property to achieve this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userInventory"
           class="col-2 c-pointer"
           (click)="addItemToArray(item)"
           [attr.disabled]="item.isAdded">
        <img src="{{item.image}}" class="img-fluid"/>
        <span class="d-block">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this solution. Unfortunately Angular throws with the exception `compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'`

Comment: @filipbarak in that case use `attr.disabled`. I have updated my answer

Comment: `div` doesn't have `disabled` attribute